# getting core data object by boolean property

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

How can I get an object by a BOOL property? For example, if I have a custom object with a BOOL property completed, how can I get only the ones where `completed = true`? I'm using Magical Record

```
[CustomObject MR_findByAttribute:@"completed" withValue:true];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `searchValue` argument of `MR_findByAttribute:withValue:` must be a reference to an object, but `true` is not a reference to an Objective-C object.  It is a “primitive” value.  You must wrap it in an `NSValue` object.

Also, in Objective-C we normally use the constants `YES` and `NO` as the boolean constants.

You can get an `NSValue` wrapper for `YES` just by saying `@YES`, so try this:

```
NSArray *completedObjects = [CustomObject MR_findByAttribute:@"completed"
    withValue:@YES];
```

Comment: you learn something new everyday. Thanks for the tip, this works perfectly.